# How to prevent search engine indexing of common utility words without JS

Tags: html, search-engine

Google thinks my site is about ago, cancel, and edit. This is because those words appear on every comment. Why am I the only site who seems to suffer from this problem?

In fact, if you search Google for the words ago, cancel, and edit (without quotes), my site comes up in the #2 spot (right below Stack Overflow in spot #1). Even if Google is not smart enough to filter out these words, should not sites like reddit, who also use these same text buttons show up before mine?

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=ago+cancel+edit

Sites like reddit do not use JavaScript to cloak keywords, so they have found a non-JS solution. What gives?

Thank you.

EDIT: The website is popstrip.com and you can see the comment code at the bottom of any comic page.

Comment: Why do you mind? Are there people who are searching for "ago cancel edit" then arriving at your site and complaining? Which site do you think they should be finding? Maybe they are finding your site and are happy.

Comment: I mind because Google rank is largely dependent on what your site is about. I'd rather Google actually know what my site is about, so when people search for keywords related to my site, they get my site.

Comment: For me, your site isn't showing in the top few pages of results, so it might just be a google personalised search for you that is causing this. I think you are crazy to spend time thinking about this. No one else has ever complained that they are ranked too highly by Google. I really think you shouldn't worry about unimportant keywords, and concentrate on how you rank for keywords you do care about.

Comment: The site has been down almost a month, so it's not in Google anymore. Again, no one is complaining about a high Google ranking, but about Google not understanding what the site is about (it considered ago, cancel, and edit the top keywords on the site). Whenever this issue was happening, obviously there were far more popular sites that used those same keywords (even more frequently) and didn't suffer the issue -- so somehow it is avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [google support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=4790fe490de7a55e&hl=en), so it looks like Google doesn't think it's possible without Javascript or an iframe.

Comment: How do you think other sites prevent this? The words are ago, cancel, and, edit are pretty commonly used.

Comment: I don't think other sites prevent this. I think that you are amazingly lucky to have got a site that is outranking them.